# Best method to extract data from dynamoDb and move it to another table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, extract, etl

I have a table of 500gb. I want to transfer the data to another table based on the timestamps.
There are several items in table and I want only latest entry of every item in another table.

Considering the size of table, can anyone recommend best aws service to get it done fast and easy?

I have come across aws glue, hivecopyactivity. Are this the best solution or is there any other service I can use?

Comment: what's the partition key and sort key (if any) of that table? 

"based on the timestamps": is there a timestamp field in every item? if not, where is the timestamp of an item defined? 

how many global secondary indexes do you have on that table?

Comment: one more question, regarding "I want only the latest entry of every item". what happens when the original table is updated (an entry with a newer timestamp is added). do you want the second table to be updated as well? if so, then what's the propagation delay that your application can tolerate?

Comment: @ItayMaman The table will be freeze during the time of extraction. Yes, there is timestamp for every entry in DB. Partition and sort key are different. I am interested in another column for which I want the latest entry.

Comment: "latest entry": latest entry with the same primary key? with the same primary key +  sort key? something else?

Comment: @ItayMaman Something else. there is column x:String which is neither a primary key nor a sort key. I have to get the latest entry of x.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you now can add a Global secondary indexes (GSI) on that table, that is: you currently have < 5 GSIs)

Define a new GSI on your table. The GSI's partition key will be `x`. The GSI's sort key will be `timestamp`. Once you have that GSI defined you can do a [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) on that index with `ScanIndexForward` set to `false` to get the most recent item first. You need to supply the value of `x` you are interested at. In the following example request it is simply set to `'abc'`

```
{
    "TableName": "<your-table-name>",
    "IndexName": "<your-GSI-name>",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "x = :argx",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":argx": {"S": "abc"}
    },
    "ScanIndexForward": false,
    "Limit": 1
}
```

This query looks at items with a given `x` value (as set in the `ExpressionAttributeValues` field) sorted in descending order (by the GSI's sort key, which is the `timestamp` field) and picks the first one (`Limit` is set to `1`). As long as *you do not need filtering* (the `FilterExpression` field is empty) then you will get the result that you need by issuing a single Query request.

If you *do* want to use filtering you will need to do multiple requests and unset the `Limit` field (i.e., use its default value). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57702153/dynamodb-how-to-query-n-elements-starting-at-x-index/57720494#57720494) for further details on those subtleties.

Comment: Sorry, I got some new info. The column I am interested in,  is a sort key. Would it change you answer? @ItayMaman

Comment: Is 'x' the sort key or is 'timestamp' the sort key?

Comment: x is the sort key

Comment: Then my answer does not change

Comment: Now the requirements  have changed. Now I need to take into account two columns and timestamp. So, now I need the latest entry for every unique combination of two columns x and y.  @ItayMaman

Comment: In that case I would advise to introduce a new field (lets call it `xy`) which contains the concatenation of `x` and `y`. You need to update your insertion code to have this field populated for all new items. you will also have to write a one-time program that scan the entire DB and backfills this field in old items. 

Then you need to define your index with `xy` as its partition key.  Note that you can define the index even before the backfill completes.